# How to do looping in GSP?

Tags: grails, gsp

I have GSP file in which i will be getting a value from the controller say for example `${paramsValue?.ruleCount}` is 3 and based on that I have to create table rows.

Is there any way to do it in gsp

Answer (score 25, accepted):

what about

```
<g:each in="${(1..paramsValue?.ruleCount).toList()}" var="count" >
   ...
</g:each>
```

?

But it would be nicer if you would prepare a list with the content to be displayed in your controller...

Update:

just gave it a try:

```
<% def count=5 %>
<g:each in="${(1..count).toList()}" var="c" >
  ${c}
</g:each>
```

works.

```
<% def count=5 %>
<g:each in="${1..count}" var="c" >
  ${c}
</g:each>
```

works too and is even shorter.

Update2:

It seems that you want to use an URL parameter as count. This code will work in that case:

```
<g:each in="${params.count?1..(params.count as Integer):[]}" var="c" >
  ${c}
</g:each>
```

it will check if there is a count-parameter. If not, it will return an empty list to iterate over. If count is set, it will cast it to Integer, create a Range and implicitly convert it to a list to iterate over.

Comment: what's the error message you are getting - could it be that your `paramsValue?.ruleCount` is not a number? then try `paramsValue?.ruleCount as Integer`

Comment: Yes, bust still I had a casting exception,org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error evaluating expression [1..paramsValue?.ruleCount as Integer] on line [162]: Cannot cast object '1..50' with class 'groovy.lang.ObjectRange' to class 'java.lang.Integer'
 at C__RMSWorkSpacewithServiceRMS_rmsportal_grails_app_views_requestService_submit_gsp$_run_closure2.doCall(submit.gsp:175)
 at C__RMSWorkSpacewithServiceRMS_rmsportal_grails_app_views_requestService_submit_gsp.run(submit.gsp:1)

Comment: see my updated code... it has to be `[1..(paramsValue?.ruleCount as Integer)]` instead of `[1..paramsValue?.ruleCount as Integer]`